# GPGPU Applications other than Image processing?

Tags: cuda, gpu, gpgpu

I am in search for few cpu applications which can be ported to gpgpu for better efficiency.
Else where can gpgpu be used other than image processing area ?
This is actually for my graduate project.

Comment: Raytracing, simulations, basically anything that requires parallel floating point operations.

Comment: @Blender actually raytracing involves a lot of branching, so is not ideal to the SIMD architecture of moderm GPGPU

Comment: i mean, if you want to find more efficient ways to do raytracing, thats a neat project, but i guess there are no good ways to do it right now, otherwise we would have real-time raytracers by now

Comment: Did you read the [wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GPGPU#Applications)?

Comment: NVIDIA just held a huge conference. There were literally hundreds of papers on all aspects of GPU computing and it's applications. All the material is online. If you haven't already looked at it, you aren't trying hard enough : google GTC2012. But this is off topic for SO, I have voted to close.

Comment: If there are any prevalent industries in your area, maybe look into what type computations they require and if they can be accelerated with GPUs.

Answer (score 2):

The specialized processing architectures of GPU compute engines are useful for just about any data crunching problem where you have:

1. a non-trivial amount of data
2. a non-trivial computation to perform on every element of that data,
3. the input data needed to compute each output element fits in GPU memory, or can be choreographed to arrive in GPU memory when it is needed.

It helps if the computation can be performed independently on all data elements at the same time, but this is not strictly required.

Image processing happens to be one example of that scenario - a finite (but large) number of pixels to process, and many image algorithms can be executed on each pixel in parallel.

Other examples include: generalized signal analysis, such as processing audio signals.  Image processing is just a specialized form of signal analysis. Pattern recognition, where much of the challenge is to separate the signal from the noise. Voice recognition, anyone? 3 dimensional surface matching, such as figuring out the shapes of organic compounds based on the flex angles of their chemical bonds, or figuring out if two organic compounds are likely to interact in interesting ways (eg, bioreceptors). Physical modelling of all kinds (collision simulations, seismic analysis, etc). And of course, cryptography, where you can always spend more compute time going over the same data again and again.

GPU compute engines are not well suited for problems where the volume of data significantly dwarfs the computations to be performed. GPUs work well on stuff in memory.  Moving data into or out of GPU memory is often the most expensive step of an entire computation, so you want to make sure you have enough computation going on to "make up" for the cost of loading the data into memory.  If the data is too big to fit into memory you have to adopt distributed computing tactics.

For example, calculating a primary key index of a petabyte database probably isn't a great fit for a GPU since most of the effort will probably be spent just getting the data off the hard disk into memory. The index computation itself is fairly trivial, which doesn't make for a very interesting GPU win, and while I'm sure the data could be carved up into chunks and the chunks indexed independently by a boatload of GPU cores, variability in the data will likely prevent the GPU from operating at its full capacity.  (GPU code works best when all "oarsmen" (processor cores / threads) are pulling in the same direction - uniform execution on separate data) While database indexing might see some benefit by using a GPU approach, it certainly won't be as big of a performance improvement over CPU baseline as something better suited to the GPU execution model constraints - like signal processing.

Answer (score 0):

Brute force crypto attacks? MD5 has been done by [Whitepixel](http://whitepixel.zorinaq.com/) and SHA-256 has been done by all the Bitcoin miners. On the other hand, I am not aware of any GPU implementations of `bcrypt()` or `scrypt()`, but an academic working in the area is probably a better person to ask.

Answer (score 0):

Easiest way to figure out what kinds of applications are well-suited for GPGPU is to look at the speedups other groups have achieved.  Here are a couple of links with that information:

- [NVIDIA's case studies](http://www.nvidia.com/object/cuda-apps-flash-new.html)
- [AccelerEyes' case studies](http://accelereyes.com/examples)

Looks like military/aerospace, life science, energy, finance, manufacturing, media, and a few other smaller industries have examples of strong speedups.